# Qual è il significato di "pescare" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel libro *I migliori anni della nostra vita* di Ernesto Ferrero ho letto:

> A un angolo di una lunga tavolata, un po' appartato, Marcello Mastroianni **pescava** con un pezzo di pane da un tegamino dove gli avevano preparato due uova al burro. Pareva saturato dalla speciale pazienza che hanno le persone consapevoli che in fondo la vita è una lunga attesa, un intervallo da riempire con due uova al tegamino.

Ho cercato il significato del verbo "pescare" in parecchi dizionari, tuttavia non riesco a coglierne il senso in questo passaggio. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'utilizzo di pescare in questo contesto non lo ritengo di uso comune ma figurativo del tirare su dal piatto l'uovo con il pane.
Treccani definisce "pescare" come

> prendere, tirare su qualcosa scegliendola a caso fra molte altre
>   analoghe: p. una carta dal mazzo; ha pescato l’asso di cuori; p. un
>   numero

Nonostante in questo caso non stia effettivamente scegliendo a caso fra molte altre analoghe ritengo possa essere compreso in questo senso.

"Pescare" indica anche il

> Venire in possesso di qualcosa, riuscire a trovare qualcosa o qualcuno

quindi *pescare* l'uovo con il pane vuol dire andare a "cercare" l'uovo con il pane nel tegamino.

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/pescare/

Answer (score 2):

Significa che usava il pane per raccogliere il cibo dal tegamino a mo' di cucchiaio o spatola; è quel gesto che viene di solito chiamato "*fare la scarpetta*"